# Multiwindow Apps in Android

Tags: android, facebook, webview, rss

I am developing android application to use multiple window in same window. 
I am including multiple layouts with multiple purpose. For example one part of window will have browser and one part has to display Facebook or twitter news feed, and one more to display current news which can be get from rss feed.

For the browser I am using `WebView` in which user can search some thing in browser. 
But if I use webview to search something it is opened in android browser.

Is there anyway to display webpages with in `Webview` and if I search anything It should also be displayed with in web view?

Guide me in right way.

Comment: you have to use just `loadUrl();` method

Comment: But it opens a browser with the url.

Comment: Download Demo from : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/AndroidWebViewExample.zip

Comment: Here Example that you want : http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-webview-example.html

Comment: loadUrl method opens the browser. I do not want this. I want to load the it with in webview

Comment: w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       view.loadUrl(url);
       view.requestFocus();
        //  view.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/search?q="+e.getText().toString());
          return false;
      }
  });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44308/discussion-between-pratik-butani-and-sathish)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution .

```
WebView view =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: This shouldoverrideUrlLoading() method is not executed.